# uniquely identify click and execute once

Tags: jquery

```
<div id = uni1>
        <input type=button class=click rel="1">
</div>
<div id = uni2>
        <input type=button class=click rel="2">
</div>
<div id = uni3>
        <input type=button class=click rel="3">
</div>
<div id = uni4>
        <input type=button class=click rel="4">
</div>

$(".click").click(function()
{
    alert("Help");
})
```

i have problem identifying the click button for jquery this will prompt alert 4 times.
"#uni1 .click" will allow me to identify 
BUT I CANNOT static DEFINE this.
MEAN i can only use .click. because MY uni1 <-- is DYNAMIC i can have up to uni100.
or Uni10000(This is User Choice to have number of uni)

my question would be how am i going to identify uniquely each button for each input type.
after the button is click i can use

```
$(".click").click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().attr('id');
//it doesn't solve the problem that alert will still be executed 4 times. i want to have click being uniquely identify upon user click.
    alert("Help");
})

<div id=uni>
    <div id = uni1>
            <input type=button class=click rel="1">
    </div>
    <div id = uni2>
            <input type=button class=click rel="2">
    </div>
    <div id = uni3>
            <input type=button class=click rel="3">
    </div>
    <div id = uni4>
            <input type=button class=click rel="4">
    </div>
</div>

$("#uni"+i).load(abc.html,function(){ $(".click").click(funcion(){ alert("help");})})
```

Comment: Why 4 times? the `alert` will be executed just 1 time 1 click.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3yQ4W/ Works just fine to me

Comment: is it because of the reattach? for my function that cause it to load 4 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your example and it works fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/3yQ4W/

If it's  prompted 4 times it's either because you've declared it 4 times or because you have some weird loop in there that you are not showing us.

EDIT:

```
$("body").on('click','.click',function(){
   alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: What you gave us is not the problem. Look somewhere else, you must be declaring the same thing again. Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/3yQ4W/

Comment: is it possible that my reattaching of html causing the problem i didn't write any loop

Comment: technically i can't paste my whole file because there is alot file link to the main for using load function.

Comment: EDited my answer. Use that code so you don't have to declare it twice. And of course, remove it from the  .load callback function

Comment: if i have multiple function on .load. i can just execute it using $("body").on to attach the function once. later on it is not necessary to reattach it again?

Comment: Exactly, .on works as the old .live. Useful when you add elements to the DOM on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to use closure.
The Javascript can be something like this:

```
(function(){
  var inputs = $(".click");

  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].onclick = (function(n){
                           return function(){
                                   alert(n)
                                  }
                         })(i)    
  }

})()
```

So each link has its own onclick event. Click one will alert its index of the inputs array.
Also you can check out jsfiddle:　http://jsfiddle.net/zhujy_8833/YWr7z/